# Why Ubuntu doesn't load settings from my .bashrc/.profile for apps not started from bash?

Tags: launcher, environment-variables, session, bashrc

At other and previous distros it was common for me to have the environment setup in .bashrc/.profile applied globally, whether I started applications from bash or not (IIRC).

Now when I start applications from launcher icons or when clicking files with associated applications, they don't inherent my environment configuration.

Why of this now?

and

How can I get the desired behavior or what's the right way for this?

Disclaimer: I've already set some vars from my .bashrc by putting the exports at a .xsessionrc file, but I'd really like an approach where I put configurations in a single file without having duplicated setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout my other answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/325851/152691), I'm using `.pam_enviroment` and `.profile`/`.bashrc` for a global setup.