# Why this .pam_environment setting prevents me from logging in?

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc, .profile, pam-environment

I'm trying to move things from my `.bashrc` to `.pam_enviroment` because of [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/325434/152691). I've put the following into my `.pam_environment` but this prevents me from logging in because there should be some mistake. I've then removed `.pam_environment` while in recovery mode.

```
VISUAL       DEFAULT=/usr/local/bin/vim
EDITOR       DEFAULT=/usr/local/bin/vim
PATH         DEFAULT=/usr/local/src/rbenv/bin:$PATH
WORKON_HOME  DEFAULT=$HOME/.virtualenv
GOROOT       DEFAULT=/usr/local/src/go
PATH         DEFAULT=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
GOPATH       DEFAULT=$HOME/.go
PATH         DEFAULT=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
PATH         DEFAULT=$PATH:/usr/local/src/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-build
PATH         DEFAULT=$PATH:/usr/local/src/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-view
PATH         DEFAULT=$PATH:/usr/local/src/.build/kint/bin
M2_HOME      DEFAULT=/opt/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.5
M2           DEFAULT=$M2_HOME/bin
PATH         DEFAULT=$M2:$PATH
JAVA_HOME    DEFAULT=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
PATH         DEFAULT=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
ECLIPSE_HOME DEFAULT=/opt/eclipse
PATH         DEFAULT=$ECLIPSE_HOME:$PATH
```

What's the problem with these settings? As I said in my previous question, I'm still trying to figure out a good way to have global settings for all my applications, as it worked before when `.profile/.bashrc` was enough for this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've learned from the web of [someone that got in the same trouble](http://somethinggroovy.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/pamenvironment-syntax-in-ubuntu.html). `.pam_environment` syntax for referring to variables **must** include curly braces, fixing this has solved the problem:

```
VISUAL       DEFAULT=/usr/local/bin/vim
EDITOR       DEFAULT=/usr/local/bin/vim
PATH         DEFAULT=/usr/local/src/rbenv/bin:${PATH}
WORKON_HOME  DEFAULT=${HOME}/.virtualenv
GOROOT       DEFAULT=/usr/local/src/go
PATH         DEFAULT=${PATH}:${GOROOT}/bin
GOPATH       DEFAULT=${HOME}/.go
PATH         DEFAULT=${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin
PATH         DEFAULT=${PATH}:/usr/local/src/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-build
PATH         DEFAULT=${PATH}:/usr/local/src/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-view
PATH         DEFAULT=${PATH}:/usr/local/src/.build/kint/bin
M2_HOME      DEFAULT=/opt/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.5
M2           DEFAULT=${M2_HOME}/bin
PATH         DEFAULT=${M2}:${PATH}
JAVA_HOME    DEFAULT=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
PATH         DEFAULT=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
ECLIPSE_HOME DEFAULT=/opt/eclipse
PATH         DEFAULT=${ECLIPSE_HOME}:${PATH}
```

I don't find it a best approach, but what I'm doing now is setting variables at `.pam_environment` for them to take effect for any application (not just the ones started from bash) and putting setup that requires additional logic beyond trivial assignment into `.profile`/`.bashrc`.